How can I make the layout of the interface fit other screen resolutions,?
How to make the layout of the interface in the program on other computers with a different screen size (resolution) was the same as on my computer. For example: I run the program on my computer and everything is fine with the interface, but as soon as I run it on another (smaller or bigger) computer, the interface is not the same as mine. How can I make the interface on other computers be the same as mine?
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


def open_second_window():
    second_window = tk.Toplevel(root)
    second_window.title("window")
    second_window.state('zoomed')

    image_path = "1.jpg"
    image = Image.open(image_path)
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)

    label = tk.Label(second_window, image=photo)
    label.image = photo 
    label.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
    label.place(x=770, y=0)

    button = tk.Button(second_window,height=4, width=12, font='Times 31', text="ONE", command=lambda: open_four_window(second_window))

    button.place(x=308, y=82, anchor='ne')
    button1 = tk.Button(second_window,height=4, width=12, font='Times 31', wraplength=289, text="TWO", command=open_five_window)
    button1.place(x=688, y=82, anchor='ne')
    button = tk.Button(second_window,height=4, width=12, font='Times 31', text="THREE", command=open_threee_window)
    button.place(x=308, y=352, anchor='ne')
    button1 = tk.Button(second_window,height=4, width=12, font='Times 31', text="FOUR", command=open_threetenfive_window)
    button1.place(x=688, y=352, anchor='ne')


    tk.Label(second_window, font='Times 30', text="text", fg="red").place(x=150, y=30)


    third_window.grab_set()
def open_four_window(second_window):
    second_window.destroy()

    four_window = tk.Toplevel(root)
    four_window.title("win")
    four_window.state('zoomed')

    image_path = "2.jpg"
    image = Image.open(image_path)
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)

    label = tk.Label(four_window, image=photo)
    label.image = photo  
    label.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
    label.place(x=0, y=0)


    button = tk.Button(four_window,height=1, width=33, font='Times 31', text="Start", command=lambda: open_second_window())
    button.place(x=768, y=720, anchor='ne')
    button1 = tk.Button(four_window,height=1, width=33, font='Times 31', text="Exit", command=Close)
    button1.place(x=1536, y=720, anchor='ne')



    third_window.grab_set()

///
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("menu")
root.state('zoomed')


image_path = "40.jpg"
image = Image.open(image_path)
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
image.thumbnail((1, 1))

label = tk.Label(root, image=photo)
label.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
label.place(x=-3, y=0)

def Close(): 
    root.destroy() 

button = tk.Button(root,height=1, width=33, font='Times 31', text="Start", command=lambda: open_second_window())
button.place(x=768, y=720, anchor='ne')
button1 = tk.Button(root,height=1, width=33, font='Times 31', text="Exit", command=Close)
button1.place(x=1536, y=720, anchor='ne')


tk.Label(root, font='Times 30', text="text", fg="red").place(x=150, y=30)
tk.Label(root, font='Times 30 italic', text="description").place(x=600, y=77)

root.mainloop()


It would be easier for people to help if you removed the images from your example, and replaced them with a label or canvas or frame with the same size.

Without knowing what you want your UI to look like, it's going to be very difficult for us to help. As a rule of thumb, my recommendation is to not use place. Both pack and grid make it much easier to create a responsive UI.

You may be encountering this problem because you set the x and y positions as fixed. If you want the dimensions of the components to change according to the screen resolution, you can use the place function with relwidth and relheight parameters, e.g.:
button.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.9, relwidth=0.25, relheight=0.1, anchor='ne')


I have everything works (interface, texts, etc.), except for the photo, how to make the photo have the same size on different computers with different screen sizes?
